Display language in Problems debug tab is wrong
Somehow, in VS Code the Problems section in debugger is translated to Chinese, but my display language is English.

I have my Display language set to English. My Preferred Languages are:

English
Chinese

Region: Taiwan
Regional Format: English
Even have my Language for non-Unicode programs in Administrative language settings is set to English.
Why is the window in Chinese and how can I make it appear in English?
